# Difference between Integrated Windows Authentication and Windows Digest Authetication in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

I am working on ASP.NET web application that will be used on intranet and need to implement authentication using Active Directory domain accounts.

From what I understand there are 2 possible options:

1. Integrated Windows Authentication
2. Windows Digest Authentication

Can I use either of them? It is clear that Windows Digest Authentication supports authentication using Active Directory domain accounts. Integrated Windows Authentication definitely can use local Windows accounts but I am not sure about AD accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now answer my own question because I completed my implementation for this:  Integrated Windows Authentication can use AD account just the same way as local Windows account.